How to solve a non-linear equation in a state space model
So I'm trying to model a four wheeled robot that is controlled by the difference in speeds between both sides of the wheels.
I have 3 state variables:
Sway velocity, yaw rate and yaw angle respectively: let's call them  \$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\$.
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 = v\\
x_2 = r \\
x_3 = \Psi
\end{cases}
$$
I then have 3 equations for describing the system.
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}_1 = \left( \dfrac{2 K_v K_t}{R_w} \right) \cdot \dfrac{(u_L + u_R) x_1}{V_T} - K_s x_1 + V_T x_2\\
\dot{x}_2 = K_y R_m (u_L - u_R) - V_T x_2 + K_D x_1\\
\dot{x}_3 = x_2
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation for sway velocity is non-linear due to the terms \$(u_L + u_R) x_1\$. That is, the input variables \$u_L,u_R\$ are multiplied by \$x_1\$.
What technique should I use to convert these equations into a state space model of the form:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^\prime\!\! = Ax + Bu\\
y = Cx + Du
\end{cases}\;?
$$

Isn't the usual technique to linearize around an operating point?  You could also use numerical techniques to solve the non-linear system (e.g. SPICE).
